# Why get login failed while click on login button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

If i click on login button my username and password is same as condition but get login failed in `Toast Message`. Insert correct username and password compiler going to else part. I don't know what is the problem. I am stuck from 4 hours. If you know please solve i am a newbie.

Here down is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView Username=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        TextView password=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);

        Button loginbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Username.getText().toString().equals("ADMIN") && password.getText().toString().equals("ADMIN")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Faild!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backs"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_outline_24"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittext" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Forgot password"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.837"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/other"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="288dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="or sign in with"
        android:textColor="#BDB9B9"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/other"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/google" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Im not an android developer but cant it be that you are getting a TextView in your code for password but have it as a EditText in your xml

Comment: Yes i can checked its have no restriction for password field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the `R.id.Username` component which is the `SIGN UP` text and you are casting the fields as `TextView`s instead of `EditText`s.

Change your variables to:

```
EditText Username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. much appreciation for your correct anwer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the text from the wrong reference, Change the below code to later.

```
TextView Username=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Username);
```

to

```
TextView Username=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```